# How to use regular expressions to only capture a word by itself rather than in another word?

Tags: python, regex, string

How to use regular expressions to only capture a word by itself rather than the word inside another word?

For example, I'd like to replace only the "Co" within "Company & Co."

```
import re
re.subn('Co','',"Company & Co")
>>('mpany & ', 2) #which i dont want
>> "Company & "#Desired Result
```

Comment: do you have a period following Co or not? your code says you do not ... but your quoted strings in the text say you do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
import re
print re.subn('Co$','',"Company & Co")
```

these are called [metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters), that are very useful and worth looking at.

Comment: What's the difference in using $ and \b in front of and end of the word?

Comment: $ - matches at the end of a line, \b - matches only at the beginning or end of a word

Comment: you can get detailed info about these at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters

Answer (score 3):

"Word itself" means that the word is spanned by spaces or beginning/end of the sentence. So...

```
re.subn('(\s|^)Co(\s|$)','\g<1>\g<2>',"Company & Co")
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [*word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

They are expressed with `\b` in most regex dialects (and with `\<` and `\>` in some). Python uses `\b`.

```
import re
re.subn(r'\bCo\b', '', "Company & Co")
```

note the `r` in front of the pattern.

Comment: why is the r important in front of the pattern? I never use it and things seem to work just fine.

Comment: @Chris Because it marks strings as *raw strings*. With the `r` no escape sequences are interpreted (i.e., all backslashes are taken literally), which is rather useful for defining regular expressions. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals (Hint: `re.subn('\\bCo\\b' ...` would work as well, but `'\b'` alone does not, because `\b` is the escape sequence for a backspace character.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `r"\b"` expression to match the empty string at the beginning or end of what you're looking for to ensure that it's a whole word and not part of another word:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat1 = re.compile("Co")
>>> pat2 = re.compile(r"\bCo\b")
>>> pat1.match("Company")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106b92780>
>>> pat2.search("Company")
# (fails)
>>> pat2.search("Co")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106b927e8>
>>> pat2.search("Co & Something")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106b92780> # succeeds
```

This [syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) works whether the boundary between what you're looking for is:

- white space
- beginning of string
- end of string